# HTML/Javascript Display User input (Refresh Issue)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, refresh

> I am trying to take what a user enters in a textbox, and then write
>   that input to a paragraph on the page, and stop the page refreshing so that they can then copy that input for use elsewhere.  (it's going to be a rather longer form, but this is a stumbling block i've hit
>   --edited for clarity--
>
> All seems to be working well, other than when I enter input and press
>   submit, the input is displaying fine for a couple seconds, then the
>   page refreshes.  Is there any way I can fix/stop this?

I have tried adding a while loop to the display for the code to stop when it has displayed, but so far no success.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thank you.

**my code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm() {
        var input = document.myForm.username.value;
            document.write.getElementById("display").innerHTML=("Your username is" + " " + input);
            }


    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Enter username" /><br/>
    <input type ="submit" value="Submit" 
    onClick="checkForm()" />

</form> 

<span id="display"><p> </p> </span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well the form submits...that is what forms do.

Answer (score 0):

Your function also needs to return false back to the html form:

```
function checkForm() {
    var input = document.myForm.username.value;
    document.write.getElementById("display").innerHTML=("Your username is" + " " + input);
    return false;
}
```

You should probably also be using the [**onsubmit**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) event of the form itself, instead of **onclick** on the submit button.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the feedback.  I know i'm missing something really obvious.  I tried adding the return false, and also removed onclick and changed the form to onsubmit, but it still has the refresh issue.  I'm still pretty new to this, and im banging my head trying to figure out what i'm missing lol.

Answer (score 0):

mate, on a submit button, it defaults to submit your form that cause the page refresh, you need return false at the end of your checkForm(); or call e.preventdefault() at the end;

Answer (score 0):

There is no document.write....

```
document.write.getElementById(...
```

It should be

```
document.getElementById(...
```

And you need to cancel the form submission.

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); });
```

That needs to be attached on document ready or window onload.

Other option is to use

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem.  I realise others mentioned to return false too, which i put as part of the function, but it didn't seem to want to play nice.  So thanks to everyone for the help and feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are very new to programming

So

If your **submit tag is in form tag** it will go to forms action attributes path,if you don`t have action attribute it will refresh; since it will have "" path and it means that it is current path

For example when your code like this

```
<form action="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But if your **submit tag is not in form tag** submit tag will work like simple button tag.

```
<div>
    <input type="submit">
</div>
```

in this case you can use it for JavaScript like button.

But if you will write return false at your onclick function it will cut process of your submit and it can work in form tag too.

So to help I will write your code

```js
function output(){
    var text=document.getElementById("text");
    var value=text.value
    var outputDiv=document.getElementById("output")
    
    outputDiv.innerText=value
}
```

```css
#output{
   height:50px;
   margin-bottom:25px;
   border:1px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>

<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="output()">
```

Best regards